# Angular 5 Static Injection Error

Tags: angular

I ran into this error. I've checked the *ngFor to be sure it's not a syntax error. I also tried providing the common module maybe that will fix it but I'm still stuck on it.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgForOf -> TemplateRef]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgForOf -> TemplateRef]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for TemplateRef! Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgForOf -> TemplateRef]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgForOf -> TemplateRef]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for TemplateRef!

```html
<div *ngFor="let session of sessions">
  <!-- chat mode -->
  <div [hidden]="navState.key !== session.id">
    <!-- chat mode -->
    <div *ngIf="session.modeName === 'chat'">
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="left-ctrls">
          <div class="action"><i class="icon-stop"></i><span>Ban</span></div>
          <div class="action"><i class="icon-clock"></i><span>Expire</span></div>
          <div class="action"><i class="icon-transfer"></i><span>Transfer</span></div>
          <div class="action"><i class="icon-add"></i><span>Invite</span></div>
          <div class="action"><i class="icon-join"></i><span>Join</span></div>
          <div class="action"><i class="icon-branch"></i><span>Takeover</span></div>
          <div class="action"><i class="icon-remove"></i><span>Remove</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-nav">
          <div class="nav-link"><i class="icon-cart"></i><span>Catalog</span></div>
          <div class="nav-link"><i class="icon-folder"></i><span>FAQ</span></div>
          <div class="nav-link"><i class="icon-calendar"></i><span>History</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="page-body">
        <div class="chat-area">
          <div class="client-info">
            <div class="device-info">
              <div><i class="icon-mobile"></i></div>
              <div>
                <span>Mobile</span>
                <span>iOS/Safari</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="visit-info">
              <span>Visits</span><span>1</span>
              <span>Chats</span><span>10</span>
              <span>Orders</span><span>10</span>
              <span>questions</span><span>5</span>
              <span>Products</span><span>2</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="chat-header">
            <i class="icon-browser"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Page History</span>
          </div>
          <div class="chat-view">
            <div *ngFor="let message of session['transcript']">
                <nd-chat-bubble *ngIf="!message.isNotification" [message]="[message, session.modeName]"></nd-chat-bubble>
                <nd-chat-notification *ngIf="message.isNotification" [message]="message"></nd-chat-notification>
            </div>
          </div>
          <nd-chat-input
            [showPCSurveyBtn]="currentWork?.showSurvey"
            [sessionMode]="session.modeName"
            (messageEmitter)="handleAdvocateInput($event)"
            (showPCSurvey)="showSurvey = $event"
            ></nd-chat-input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- offline message mode -->
    <div *ngIf="session.modeName === 'forms'">
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="left-ctrls">
          <div class="action"><i class="icon-stop"></i><span>Ban</span></div>
          <div class="action"><i class="icon-transfer"></i><span>Done</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-nav">
          <div class="nav-link"><i class="icon-cart"></i><span>Catalog</span></div>
          <div class="nav-link"><i class="icon-folder"></i><span>FAQ</span></div>
          <div class="nav-link"><i class="icon-calendar"></i><span>History</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="page-body">
        <div class="chat-area">
          <div class="client-info">
            <div class="device-info">
              <div><i class="icon-mobile"></i></div>
              <div>
                <span>Mobile</span>
                <span>iOS/Safari</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="visit-info">
              <span>Visits</span><span>1</span>
              <span>Chats</span><span>10</span>
              <span>Orders</span><span>10</span>
              <span>questions</span><span>5</span>
              <span>Products</span><span>2</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="chat-header">
            <i class="icon-browser"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Page History</span>
          </div>
          <div class="chat-view">
            <div class="offline-msg-box">
                <div class="msg-header">
                  <span>OFFLINE MESSAGE</span>
                  <span class="dot"></span>
                  <span>{{session.customer}}</span>
                </div>
                <P [chatMessageBuilder]="[session.forms, session.modeName]"></P>
            </div>
          </div>
          <nd-chat-input
            [sessionMode]="session.modeName"
            (formsReply)="submitFormsReply($event)">
          </nd-chat-input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how about actual code and actual error?

Comment: @Antoniossss that's the template file that triggers the error. If I comment it, everything else works fine.

Comment: Check (or add it to your answer) HTML produced by `nd-chat-input`, `nd-chat-bubble` and `nd-chat-notification` components. This error may be caused by using `<template>` tag instead of `<ng-template>` within those components or just missing `*` char before template directives such as `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, `*ngSwitch`

Comment: Thanks @Andriy I was able to fix it eventually. The template file I posted is not where the issue came from. It actually came from where I rendered the template. So, I used `<nd-customer-chat [ngIf]="workList.length" [navState]="navState" [sessions]="sessions"></nd-customer-chat>` instead of `<nd-customer-chat *ngIf="workList.length" [navState]="navState" [sessions]="sessions"></nd-customer-chat>`