# Parsing more parameters to an Angular directive as separate parameters

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-directive

I am trying to pass two parameters to my directive as separate parameters. I manage to add the parameters as one parameter (*ovLoading="!isDataReceived;noBackground:true"), but I would like to have it as two separate parameters, is that somehow possible?:

My directive looks like this:

```
    @Directive({
    selector: `[ovLoading]`,
})
export class LoadingDirective implements OnChanges, OnInit {
    @Input() public ovLoading: boolean;
    @Input() public ovLoadingNoBackground = false;

    private factory: ComponentFactory<LoaderComponent>;
    private viewRef: EmbeddedViewRef<any>;
    private loaderComponent: ComponentRef<LoaderComponent>;

    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    ) {
        this.factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(LoaderComponent);
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
    }

    public ngOnChanges() {
        if (this.viewRef == null) {
            this.viewRef = this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        }

        if (this.ovLoading) {
            this.loaderComponent = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.factory);
            this.loaderComponent.instance.noBackground = this.ovLoadingNoBackground;
        } else if (this.loaderComponent != null) {
            this.viewContainerRef.remove(this.viewContainerRef.indexOf(this.loaderComponent.hostView));
            this.loaderComponent = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Her is how I use it (This is working):

```
<div class="header" *ovLoading="!isDataReceived;noBackground:true"></div>
```

And I would like to have it something like this (this is not working):

```
<div class="grid-view-header" *ovLoading="!isDataReceived" noBackground="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

You define your input like so:

```
@Input() public ovLoadingNoBackground = false;
```

but you use it like:

```
noBackground="true"
```

possibly if you set the input to be

```
@Input() public noBackground = false;
```

it would work.

it's possible though to do what you ask, see the following SO question:
[How to pass multiple parameter to @Directives (@Components) in Angular with TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843532/how-to-pass-multiple-parameter-to-directives-components-in-angular-with-type)

Comment: Thanks very much for you reply! I have looked at that question you are linking to before I asked my question, but can't make it work. I don't know if it is because i user *ovLoading instead of [ovLoading]? I have also tried your suggestion without any luck.

Comment: Do you get any errors or is it just the value that you get that's wrong?
 
It's possibly because you use it like that. As you suggested try 
`<div class="grid-view-header" [ovLoading]="!isDataReceived" noBackground="true">` instead

Comment: If i include the directive like [ovLoading] then I get an error: NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgIf -> TemplateRef]: when using it like *ovLoading and an additional parameter then there is no error, but the value from the additional parameter is not parsed to the directory

Comment: Never seen that before.. Had a quick check and found the following which might help or could be completely irrrelevant? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51048836/angular-5-static-injection-error

Comment: Thanks for sharing :-) But I am not sure that has anything to do with my issue :-/